# How to avoid multiple inputs from the input form in HTML?

Tags: php, html

My Ques maybe sounds like funny!!! ;) but It's so important to me!!!

Actually , I have a Voting HTML form that has 4 checkbox input and each checkbox input indicate the candidate!!!

Now I want to get the vote from the voter using php!!! But if the voter vote for multiple candidate the page will redirect to an error page says:(" You can't Vote 2 or more at once ") . otherwise (" Vote successfully").

The four input name is serially = candidate_1, candidate_2,candidate_3,candidate_4.

Please help...

Comment: Show us what you have tried - You might want to visit [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get a better idea of how SO works.

Comment: Have you tried anything? You can't be too sure if users are not logging in to your site. Maybe try with checking their IP address or something like that.

Comment: Could you post your voting form and either tell us how you are storing these votes or show the code for it?

Comment: Why not just use radio buttons instead of checkboxes?

Answer (score 2):

You should use radios instead of checkboxes :

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="candidate" value="1" id="c1" />
    <label for="c1">Candidate 1</label>
    <input type="radio" name="candidate" value="2" id="c2" />
    <label for="c2">Candidate 2</label>
    <input type="radio" name="candidate" value="3" id="c3" />
    <label for="c3">Candidate 3</label>
    <input type="radio" name="candidate" value="4" id="c4" />
    <label for="c4">Candidate 4</label>
</form>
```

Comment: What would be the php code to store the data to a   .txt file!!!? @jiboulex

Comment: This is a different question, you don't have a db storage running and you want to store the votes data in a text file ? First you should set correct rights to your files so that you should be the only one able to read it. Then I suggest you to consult the fwrite function to see how to write in files : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fwrite.php